# Derivative of the determinant map

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I have managed to show that for $A \in \text{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ the function $f: \text{Mat}(n, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(X) = \text{det}X$ is differentiable at A and that $Df(A)(H) = \text{Trace}((\text{adj}A) H)$ where $H \in \text{Mat}(n, \mathbb{R})$.

Now I have to proceed by showing that this result holds for any $A \in \text{Mat}(n, \mathbb{R})$. I have proven that $\text{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ is dense in $\text{Mat}(\mathbb{R}^n$). I'm pretty confident that we need this in order to prove the question (intuitively), but I do not know how to proceed from here.

Level: undergrad course in multidimensional real analysis.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Hint** $\det$ is a polynomial function of the coefficients so $A \mapsto Df(A)$ is continuous.

Comment: But how do I extend the domain of $Df(A)$ to $\text{Mat}(n, \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: As $f$ is $C^\infty$ on $\text{Mat}(n, \mathbb{R})$ (as a polynomial), $Df$ is defined everywhere.